# firefox displays fallback page for files mentioned in Network section that not be cached

Tags: firefox, html5-appcache

We are using HTML5 offline cache. We have polling code that checks whether the user in connected or disconnected to server/network. The online detection is done by calling one test jsp page which is mentioned in appcache file under network section. This checking works in Chrome by returning response status as 0.
But it does not work in Firefox. Firefox displays fallback page instead of giving offline status (code 0). The respone status code is still 200 in this case.
My appcache is:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
index.html

NETWORK:
TestIsOnline.jsp

FALLBACK:
/ fallback.html
```

And code to check status is:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'TestIsOnline.jsp', cache: false}).success(function(data, status) {
   console.log("user is online: status:"+status);
}).error(function(data, status) {
   console.log("user is offline: status:"+status);
});
```

And calling test page 'TestIsOnline.jsp' contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <title>To test online status</title>
</head>
<body>
  test page
</body>
</html>
```

When I disconnect server, In chrome I get output as "user is offline: status:0". 
in Firefox still I'm getting "user is online: status:200".

How to detect offline mode here?